# How to use the Python openai client with both Azure and OpenAI at the same time?

Tags: python, azure, python-module, openai-api, openai-whisper

OpenAI offers a Python client, currently in version 0.27.8, which supports both Azure and OpenAI.

Here are examples of how to use it to call the ChatCompletion for each provider:

```py
# openai_chatcompletion.py

"""Test OpenAI's ChatCompletion endpoint"""
import os
import openai
import dotenv
dotenv.load_dotenv()
openai.api_key = os.environ.get('OPENAI_API_KEY')

# Hello, world.
api_response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages=[
    {"role": "user", "content": "Hello!"}
  ],
  max_tokens=16,
  temperature=0,
  top_p=1,
  frequency_penalty=0,
  presence_penalty=0,
)

print('api_response:', type(api_response), api_response)
print('api_response.choices[0].message:', type(api_response.choices[0].message), api_response.choices[0].message)
```

And:

```py
# azure_openai_35turbo.py

"""Test Microsoft Azure's ChatCompletion endpoint"""
import os
import openai
import dotenv
dotenv.load_dotenv()

openai.api_type = "azure"
openai.api_base = os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT") 
openai.api_version = "2023-05-15"
openai.api_key = os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_KEY")


# Hello, world.
# In addition to the `api_*` properties above, mind the difference in arguments
# as well between OpenAI and Azure:
# - OpenAI from OpenAI uses `model="gpt-3.5-turbo"`!
# - OpenAI from Azure uses `engine="‹deployment name›"`! ⚠️
#   > You need to set the engine variable to the deployment name you chose when
#   > you deployed the GPT-35-Turbo or GPT-4 models.
#  This is the name of the deployment I created in the Azure portal on the resource.
api_response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
  engine="gpt-35-turbo", # engine = "deployment_name".
  messages=[
    {"role": "user", "content": "Hello!"}
  ],
  max_tokens=16,
  temperature=0,
  top_p=1,
  frequency_penalty=0,
  presence_penalty=0,
)

print('api_response:', type(api_response), api_response)
print('api_response.choices[0].message:', type(api_response.choices[0].message), api_response.choices[0].message)
```

i.e. `api_type` and other settings are globals of the Python library.

Here is a third example to transcribe audio (it uses Whisper, which is available on OpenAI but not on Azure):

```py
# openai_transcribe.py

"""
Test the transcription endpoint
https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/audio
"""
import os
import openai
import dotenv
dotenv.load_dotenv()


openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")
audio_file = open("minitests/minitests_data/bilingual-english-bosnian.wav", "rb")
transcript = openai.Audio.transcribe(
    model="whisper-1",
    file=audio_file,
    prompt="Part of a Bosnian language class.",
    response_format="verbose_json",
)
print(transcript)
```

These are minimal examples but I use similar code as part of my webapp (a Flask app).

Now my challenge is that I'd like to:

1. **Use the ChatCompletion endpoint from Azure;** but:
2. **Use the Transcribe endpoint from OpenAI (since it's not available on Azure)**

Is there any way to do so?

I have a few options in mind:

- Changing the globals before every call. But I'm worried that this might cause side-effects I did not expect.
- Duplicating/Forking the library to have two versions run concurrently, one for each provider, but this also feels very messy.
- Use an alternative client for OpenAI's Whisper, if any.

I'm not too comfortable with these and feel I may have missed a more obvious solution.

Or of course… Alternatively, I could just use Whisper with a different provider (e.g. Replicate) or an alternative to Whisper altogether.

## See also

- Someone reported the issue (but without a solution) on GitHub (openai/openai-python): [Using Azure and OpenAI at the same time #411](https://github.com/openai/openai-python/issues/411)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each API in the library accepts per-method overrides for the configuration options. If you want to access the Azure API for chat completions, you can explicitly pass in your Azure config. For the transcribe endpoint, you can explicitly pass the OpenAI config. For example:

```
import os
import openai

api_response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    api_base=os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT"),
    api_key=os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_KEY"),
    api_type="azure",
    api_version="2023-05-15",
    engine="gpt-35-turbo",
    messages=[
    {"role": "user", "content": "Hello!"}
    ],
    max_tokens=16,
    temperature=0,
    top_p=1,
    frequency_penalty=0,
    presence_penalty=0,
)
print(api_response)



audio_file = open("minitests/minitests_data/bilingual-english-bosnian.wav", "rb")
transcript = openai.Audio.transcribe(
    api_key=os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY"),
    model="whisper-1",
    file=audio_file,
    prompt="Part of a Bosnian language class.",
    response_format="verbose_json",
)
print(transcript)
```

Answer (score 1):

@Krista's answer was super useful. Here are more details that don't fit in a comment:

## Official docs

- The [official documentation for this is here](https://github.com/openai/openai-python/blob/main/README.md#microsoft-azure-endpoints) (OpenAI).
- [`api_version` is documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/reference) (Microsoft Azure)

## Whisper on Azure

You can now use Whisper from Azure:

- [Azure documentation is here for a simple REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/whisper-quickstart?tabs=command-line). Files are limited to 25 MB each. This relies on Azure OpenAI deployments.
- [Azure documentation is here for batch transcriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/batch-transcription-create?pivots=rest-api#using-whisper-models). This relies on Azure AI Speech.
- You can also use the OpenAI SDK to call Azure's Whisper. Example below.

```py
""" How to call Whisper on Azure """

import os
import time

import openai
import dotenv
dotenv.load_dotenv()



audio_file = open("minitests/minitests_data/hola-que-tal.wav", "rb")


start_time = time.time()
transcript = openai.Audio.transcribe(
    # per-method override settings for Azure:
    api_type = "azure",
    api_base = os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_WESTEUROPE_ENDPOINT"),
    api_key = os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_WESTEUROPE_KEY"),
    api_version = (
        "2023-09-01-preview"  # minimal version requirement for Whisper to work
    ),
    deployment_id="whisper",  # the name of your OpenAI deployment on Azure

    # regular settings:
    model="whisper-1",
    file=audio_file,
    response_format="verbose_json",
    language="es",
)

end_time = time.time()
print(f"API call took {end_time - start_time:.2f} seconds")

print('transcript:', type(transcript), transcript) # <class 'openai.openai_object.OpenAIObject'>
print(transcript['text'])
```

Please note:

- This is currently not documented (the docs still read "Please note that for the moment, the Microsoft Azure endpoints can only be used for completion, embedding, and fine-tuning operations.")
- Region availability is currently limited to North Central US and West Europe.
- **The rate limit / quota is currently absurdly low**: "Corresponding requests per minute (RPM) = 6", with no way to increase it from the dashboard. For comparison, OpenAI's Whisper rate limit was already low at 50 RPM.

P.S.: and, for the sake of completion, here is the same call for using per-method overrides to call Whisper from OpenAI:

```
transcript = openai.Audio.transcribe(
    # per-method override settings for OpenAI:
    api_type="openai",  # technically not needed, but makes the code clearer.
    api_key=os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY"),
    # regular settings:
    model="whisper-1",
    file=audio_file,
    response_format="verbose_json",
    language="es",
)
```