# Exception: InvalidRequestError: Resource not found

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, openai-api, openai-whisper

I want to transcribe a audio file using openai whisper model. And I am able to do it locally. But when the same code I am trying to run azure functions by creating python api. I am getting this error   `Exception: InvalidRequestError: Resource not found` I tried resolving it. but not able find why I am getting this. Anyone if has any idea then please help me.

Error:  Executed 'Functions.audio_translation' (Failed, Id=c7ae69cf-5090-46c6-b2c4-169a70e1b3ec, Duration=30574ms)
[2023-11-18T06:14:13.621Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.audio_translation. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
[2023-11-18T06:14:13.621Z] Exception: InvalidRequestError: Resource not found

**init**.py

```
import logging
import openai
import azure.functions as func
from shared_code.helper_translation import process_audio,read_audio_from_azure,read_local_files
import os
import os
from datetime import datetime
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.utils import make_chunks
from moviepy.editor import AudioFileClip
# from openai import OpenAI
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient
import requests
import openai
import logging

openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")
openai.api_version = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_VERSION")
openai.api_base = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_BASE")
openai.api_type = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_TYPE")


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    if req.method != "POST":
        return func.HttpResponse("Only POST requests are allowed.", status_code=405)
    elif req.method=="POST":

        #input_json = req.get_json()
        response_status = {}
        status_code_resp =200
        data  = read_audio_from_azure()
        logging.info(data)
        return func.HttpResponse("Request processed sucessfully", status_code=405)
```

helper_translation.py

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.utils import make_chunks
from moviepy.editor import AudioFileClip
# from openai import OpenAI
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient
import requests
import openai
import logging

openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")
openai.api_version = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_VERSION")
openai.api_base = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_BASE")
openai.api_type = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_TYPE")


output_folder = "audio_chunk"
def convert_to_mp3(audio_file_path):
    mp3_file_path = os.path.join(output_folder, os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(audio_file_path))[0] + ".mp3")

    if audio_file_path.lower().endswith(".mp4"):
        # Convert MP4 to MP3
        file_to_convert = AudioFileClip(audio_file_path)
        file_to_convert.write_audiofile(mp3_file_path)
        file_to_convert.close()
    elif audio_file_path.lower().endswith(".m4a"):
        # Convert M4A to MP3
        track = AudioSegment.from_file(audio_file_path, format='m4a')
        file_handle = track.export(mp3_file_path, format='mp3')
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unsupported audio file format for conversion. Please provide an MP4 or M4A file.")

    return mp3_file_path

def audio_chunk(audio_file_path):
        chunk_names = []
        my_audio = AudioSegment.from_file(audio_file_path)
        chunks_length_ms = 600000
        chunks = make_chunks(my_audio, chunks_length_ms)

        for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
            chunk_name = "{0}_{1}".format(i, os.path.basename(audio_file_path))
            logging.info(chunk_name)
            if(os.path.exists(output_folder)):      
                file_path = os.path.join(output_folder, chunk_name)
            else:
                os.mkdir(output_folder)
                file_path = os.path.join(output_folder, chunk_name)

            chunk_names.append(file_path)
            chunk.export(file_path, format="mp3")

        return chunk_names

def whisper_transcription(file):
    # client = OpenAI()
    defaults = {
        "engine": "whisper",
    }

    options = defaults.copy()
    logging.info(options)
    audio_file = open(file, "rb")
    transcript = openai.Audio.transcribe(
        model='whisper',
        file=audio_file,
        # **options
        )
    return transcript


def process_audio(audio_file_path):
        starttime = datetime.now()
        if audio_file_path.lower().endswith(".mp3"):
            # No need to convert, directly process the MP3 file
            audio_file_path = audio_file_path
        elif audio_file_path.lower().endswith((".m4a", ".mp4")):
            # Convert M4A or MP4 file to MP3
            audio_file_path = convert_to_mp3(audio_file_path)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unsupported video/audio file format. Please provide an MP3, M4A, or MP4 file.")

        chunk_names = audio_chunk(audio_file_path)
        
        with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            futures = [executor.submit(whisper_transcription,chunk) for chunk in chunk_names]

        transcript_file_path = os.path.join(output_folder, "transcript.txt")
        with open(transcript_file_path, "w+") as transcript_file:
            for future in futures:
                transcript = future.result()
                transcript_file.write(transcript + ".")
        file_data = open(transcript_file_path,"r")
        end_t = datetime.now() - starttime
        logging.info("Total Process Time")
        logging.info(end_t)
        return file_data

def read_audio_from_azure():
    blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="", container_name="outputfiles", blob_name="GMT20231107-075636_Recording.m4a")

    downloaded_file_path = "downloaded_audio.mp3"

    with open(downloaded_file_path, "wb") as audio_file:
        audio_file.write(blob.download_blob().readall())
    logging.info("File downloaded calling proces audio now!")
    data = process_audio(downloaded_file_path)
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

To use **Whisper Model in Open AI and Azure Open AI-API** with **Azure Functions** to transcribe speech to text, Refer this [**SO thread answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76711533/how-to-use-the-python-openai-client-with-both-azure-and-openai-at-the-same-time) by Fabien Snauwaert.

For Just **OPEN AI** you need ***Open AI API key*** and you can transcribe the audio like below:-

**My `init.py`:-**

```py
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import os
import time
import openai

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    audio_file = open("temp.wav", "rb")

    start_time = time.time()
    transcript = openai.Audio.transcribe(
        # per-method override settings for OpenAI:
        api_type="openai",
        api_key="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",
        # regular settings:
        model="whisper-1",
        file=audio_file,
        response_format="verbose_json",
        language="en",
    )
    end_time = time.time()
    logging.info(f"API call took {end_time - start_time:.2f} seconds")

    logging.info('Transcript: %s', str(transcript)) 

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        if transcript and 'text' in transcript:
            return func.HttpResponse(transcript['text'], status_code=200)
        else:
            return func.HttpResponse(
                "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
                status_code=200
            )
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

For Azure Open AI API, **`Resource not found error`** occurs when your Open AI Base or Key is incorrect or contains any incorrect character. Refer my [**SO thread answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76050070/langchains-azureopenai-error-resource-not-found/76051677#76051677) on same error.

Refer this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/whisper-quickstart?tabs=command-line&pivots=rest-api) and check if your Deployed whisper-1 model is correct and you are passing a correct name. Here's an Azure Functions **`init.py`** with Azure OpenAI:-

**`init.py:-`**

```py
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import os
import time
import openai

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    audio_file = open("temp.wav", "rb")

    start_time = time.time()
    transcript = openai.Audio.transcribe(
        # per-method override settings for Azure:
        api_type="azure",
        api_base=os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_WESTEUROPE_ENDPOINT"),
        api_key=os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_WESTEUROPE_KEY"),
        api_version="2023-09-01-preview",
        deployment_id="whisper",
        # regular settings:
        model="whisper-1",
        file=audio_file,
        response_format="verbose_json",
        language="en",
    )

    end_time = time.time()
    logging.info(f"API call took {end_time - start_time:.2f} seconds")

    logging.info('Transcript: %s', str(transcript)) 

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        if transcript and 'text' in transcript:
            return func.HttpResponse(transcript['text'], status_code=200)
        else:
            return func.HttpResponse(
                "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
                status_code=200
            )
```